# python3 RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used

Tags: apt, python3, 20.04

I have recently updated my Ubuntu from `19.10` to `20.04`. During the installation and now when I am running `apt update` I see python related warnings:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:838: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used self.stdin = io.open(p2cwrite, 'wb', bufsize)
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Off-topic, but it is already reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1863414 . There is no solution yet.

Answer (score 4):

Here, you can see a discussion about that:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue32236

And here a fix:

- https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2146

But remember ... it is not a bug, it's a feature :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no such problem with *"apt update"* in 20.4

```sh
shell> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

In my case, the problem was caused by the Ansible plugin [mitogen](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html)

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /home/admin/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/admin/.ansible/my_modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]

shell> ansible localhost -m setup
```

> /usr/lib/python3.8/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
> return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)

The problem disappeared when I disabled mitogen

```sh
shell> grep strategy ansible.cfg 
# strategy = mitogen_linear
```